# How do I transfer the frame *and* transform from one UIView to another without distortion?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview, cgaffinetransform, cgrect

I have a UIView that may have scale and/or rotation transforms applied to it. My controller creates a new controller and passes the view to it. The new controller creates a new view and tries to place it in the same location and rotation as the passed view. It sets the location and size by converting the original view's frame:

```
CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:fromView.frame fromView:fromView.superview];
ImageScrollView *isv = [[ImageScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:frame image:image];
```

This works great, with the scaled size and location copied perfectly. However, if there is a rotation transform applied to `fromView`, it does *not* transfer.

So I added this line:

```
isv.transform = fromView.transform;
```

That nicely handles transfers the rotation, but also the scale transform. The result is that the scale transform is effectively applied *twice*, so the resulting view is much too large.

So how do I go about transferring the location (origin), scale, *and* rotation from one view to another, without doubling the scale?

---

**Edit**

Here is a more complete code example, where the original UIImageView (`fromView`) is being used to size and position a UIScrollView (the ImageScrollView subclass):

```
CGRect frame = [self.view convertRect:fromView.frame fromView:fromView.superview];
frame.origin.y += pagingScrollView.frame.origin.y;
ImageScrollView *isv = [[ImageScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:frame image:image];
isv.layer.anchorPoint = fromView.layer.anchorPoint;
isv.transform = fromView.transform;
isv.bounds = fromView.bounds;
isv.center = [self.view convertPoint:fromView.center fromView:fromView.superview];
[self.view insertSubview:isv belowSubview:captionView];
```

And here is the entirety of the configuration in ImageScrollView:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame image:(UIImage *)image {
    if (self = [self initWithFrame:frame]) {
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
        imageLoaded = YES;
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.frame = rect;
        imageView.contentMode   = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self addSubview:imageView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It looks as though the transform causes the `imageView` to scale up too large, as you can see in [this ugly video](https://vimeo.com/40800069).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy the first view's `bounds`, `center`, and `transform` to the second view.

Your code doesn't work because `frame` is a value that is *derived from* the `bounds`, `center`, and `transform`. The setter for `frame` tries to do the right thing by reversing the process, but it can't always work correctly when a non-identity `transform` is set.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) is pretty clear on this point:

> If the transform property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.
>
> ...
>
> If the transform property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

Comment: Hrm, yes, that *almost* gets me there. Now the origin for the new view is not quite right.

Comment: I got the origin right by not setting the `center`. But the scale is still wrong in the new image. No matter what I do, it is scaled too large. Even if I don't have a scale transform applied, the image in the new view is still slightly too big. It's driving me crazy.

Comment: Really hard to say what your issue might be w/o seeing some code. Does this happen with a regular UIView? Are you copying all the other attributes from your old view to the new one (including any subviews)?

Comment: The old view is a UIImageView. The new one is a subclass of UIScrollView that has a UIImageView subview. The image is added to this subview, but the frame, bounds, center, and transform all come from the original UIImageView. Maybe something else needs to be transferred to the UIImageView subview of the UIScrollView? Trying to create a simple test case to demonstrate…

Comment: Oh, and the frame, bounds, center, and transform are all set on the UIScrollView. For some reason, though, the transform applied to the UIScrollView, while make its rotation perfect, has the contents of its UIImageView subview way too big. Like the scaling is passed through to the UIImageView subview. I don't get it.

Comment: Added more code details and a link to an [ugly video](https://vimeo.com/40800069) to the question.

Comment: And I *finally* figured it out: I just had to change `convertRect:fromView.frame` to `convertRect:fromView.bounds`, and now it works beautifully. I could have sworn I tried that before, but apparently not. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Let say viewA is first view that contains frame & transform, and you want to pass those values to viewB.

So that, you need to get the **original frame of viewA and pass it to viewB before pass the transform**. Otherwise, viewB's frame will be changed 1 more time on when you add transform.

To get the original frame, just make viewA.transform to **CGAffineTransformIdentity**

Here is code

```
CGAffineTransform originalTransform = viewA.transform; // Remember old transform
viewA.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity; // Remove transform so that you can get original frame
viewB.frame = viewA.frame; // Pass originalFrame into viewB
viewA.transform = originalTransform; // Restore transform into viewA
viewB.transform = originalTransform; // At this step, transform will change frame and make it the same with viewA
```

After that, viewA & viewB will have the same UI on superView.